# For/foreach loop crashing CGI server

Tags: perl

I need to write some perl scripts for a class which include some for or foreach loops. For some reason even the simplest for loop are just returning a 500 server error. I've checked many times and the code also works on codepad.org, but I dont know why it is not working on the server.
I dont have access to the server logs so I can't really tell whats going on.
These are some very simple loops that are also causing the error.

```
@a=(2,3,4);
  foreach my $r (@a) { 
      print $r;
  }
```

or

```
 @a=(2,3,4);
  for ($i = 0; $i <= 2 ; $i++) {
        print $a[$i];

    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know perl, but for the second one,  will it cause index out of bound

Comment: No, it wont. That code works fine on codepad.org

Comment: You do need those logs.  But do the above code snippets each represent the entirety of a cgi script, or just the part you think causes the crash?

Comment: They are the part that causes the crash.

Comment: Please show your *complete* program. I am sure this is something straightforward. Does it still crash if you replace this code by `print 2, 3, 4`? Or with just `@a=(2,3,4)`?

Comment: It's at line 360: http://pastebin.com/139fjFmK

Comment: Tthat's not acceptable. That's not a minimal, runnable demonstration of the problem. At the very least, provide the error message you got! Let me know (by replying with a message containing @ikegami) when you're done rephrasing your question so I can remove the -1

Comment: (If you can't access the logs, change STDERR to go somewhere you can
 read.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time you are writing a CGI script, put this at the top while you are working on it:

```
 use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
```

This will give redirect errors in your Perl script to the browser window.  It should give you a better idea of what is causing your problem (assuming it is at the script level).

It also lets you easily send your own errors and test statements to the browser using `die`:

```
die "testing 1 2 3";
```

This can be useful for doing quick debugging.

Comment: Thanks! this allowed me to see the error, which was a a missing 'my' global declaration because of the strict way the code is typed.